# Don't understand why if-else for loop not working

Tags: r, for-loop

Just can't seem to find where this call went wrong.I'm trying to make a new column to show fantasy points earned and the kick_distance of a "good" field_goal_result determines this.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(kickers)) {
 if (kickers$field_goal_result[i] == "good" & kickers$kick_distance[i] < 40) {
   kickers$fantasy_points_added[i] <- 3 
 } else if (kickers$field_goal_result[i] == "good" & kickers$kick_distance[i] > 39 & kickers$kick_distance[i] < 50) {
     kickers$fantasy_points_added[i] <- 4
   } else if (kickers$field_goal_result[i] == "good" & kickers$kick_distance[i] > 49) {
     kickers$fantasy_points_added[i] <- 5
   } else {
   kickers$fantasy_points_added[i] <- NA
 }
}

Error in if (kickers$field_goal_result[i] == "good" & kickers$kick_distance[i] <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Looks like you have `NA`s in `kickers$field_goal_result`? An if statement doesn't know what to do when the comparison is `NA`, and so it fails.

Comment: ohhhh. yes there def is bc not all observations are for field goal results (some are extra points). any way to fix this without getting rid of observations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this is with nested `ifelse` instead:

```
kickers$fantasy_points_added <- ifelse(
  kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance < 40, 
  3,
  ifelse(
    kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance > 39 & kickers$kick_distance < 50,
    4,
    ifelse(
      kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance > 49,
      5, 
      NA
    )
  )
)
```

Or using `dplyr`'s `case_when`:

```
kickers$fantasy_points_added <- dplyr::case_when(
  kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance < 40 ~ 3,
  kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance > 39 & kickers$kick_distance < 50 ~ 4,
  kickers$field_goal_result == "good" & kickers$kick_distance > 49 ~ 5,
  TRUE ~ NA
)
```

Comment: that did the trick! did not know about the case_when function! that will be immensely helpful. thank you